# Call property programmatically in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.3

I have a Ruby project where I programmatically get the names of keys in a hash I need to access. I can access the fields I need in the following way:

```
current_content = entry.fields[property_name.to_sym]
```

However, it seems that some content can only be accessed with a property syntax:

```
m.title_with_locales = {'en-US' => 'US Title', 'nl' => 'NL Title'}
```

Since I don't know "title" ahead of time, how can I make a call programmatically? Ex:

```
m.${property_name}_with_locales = {'en-US' => 'US Title', 'nl' => 'NL Title'}
```

Comment: note the usage of `public_send` in the linked question and never use `send` unless you know why you do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [#send](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Object.html#method-i-send) to programmatically access properties:

```
m.send("#{property_name}_with_locales")
# => { 'en-US' => 'US Title', ... }
```

If you need to access a setter and pass in values, you can do:

```
m.send("#{property_name}_with_locales=", { 'whatever' => 'value' })
```

Answer (score 0):

beside `send` as @gwcodes had written, there are also, `eval` and `call`.

```
2.3.1 :010 > a
 => [1, 2, 3] 
2.3.1 :011 > a.send("length")
 => 3 
2.3.1 :012 > a.method("length").call
 => 3 
2.3.1 :013 > eval "a.length"
 => 3
```

[as shown on this blog post](http://blog.khd.me/ruby/ruby-dynamic-method-calling/) `call` is a bit faster than `send`.

Comment: beware old benchmarks - from 2008! :-) This isn't true in more recent versions of Ruby, and `send` should actually be faster (but we're talking minuscule differences here)

Comment: sorry, i've not updated myself -))

Comment: Never use `eval` unless you absolutely positively have to and understand the consequences of doing so (i.e. the danger of introducing a remote code execution vulnerability if someone manages to inject unintended ruby code).

Comment: Also, the linked benchmark is seriously flawed since the expensive part of using `a.method("length").call`, namely the generation of the method object, is left out of the benchmark. If you include it in the loop, the fastest option will again be `send` respectively `public_send`